# Scala Spark: Parse SQL string to Column

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I have two functions, foo and bar, that I want to write like follows:

```
def foo(df : DataFrame, conditionString : String) = 
  val conditionColumn : Column = something(conditionString) //help me define "something"
  bar(df, conditionColumn)
}
def bar(df : DataFrame, conditionColumn : Column) = {
  df.where(conditionColumn)
}
```

Where condition is a sql string like `"person.age >= 18 AND person.citizen == true"` or something.

Because reasons, I don't want to change the type signatures here. I feel this should work because if I *could* change the type signatures, I could just write:

```
def foobar(df : DataFrame, conditionString : String) = {
  df.where(conditionString)
}
```

As `.where` is happy to accept a sql string expression.

So, how can I turn a string representing a column expression into a column? If the expression were just the name of a single column in `df` I could just do `col(colName)`, but that doesn't seem to take the range of expressions that `.where` does.

If you need more context for why I'm doing this, I'm working on a databricks notebook that can only accept string arguments (and needs to take a condition as an argument), which calls a library I want to take column-typed arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [functions.expr](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#expr(expr:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column):

```scala
def expr(expr: String): Column
```

> Parses the expression string into the column that it represents